# External executables being automatically shut down when Web App is deployed on Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, web, process, executable

I have a Web App / API that lets you run instances of a simple .exe file when you do /api/startnewfleet. This works perfectly on my machine and I can run the command from any other device on my LAN and it starts up instances of the exe file on the hosting computer. However when I deploy this to Azure it starts the process with no errors, but when I check if any processes except the web app is running its not there.

I tried query any info about the process and it says "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.;" how to get around this problem?

```
            Fleet newFleetInstance = new Fleet(Server.server, Address, (BasePort + FLEETS).ToString(), Server.ServerName + " --- Fleet " + FLEETS + 1);
        Process p;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                p = newFleetInstance.Run();
            }catch(Exception e) {
                return ("Failed: " + e.Message);
            }

            Fleets.Add(newFleetInstance);

            if (!newFleetInstance.isValid)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to boot up new server instance");
                return "Failed to boot up new server instance";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        string responding = "";
        string PName = "";
        string VMsize = "";



        //
         // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         //
        //FAILS HERE - Process has already been killed by Azure
        try{
            responding = p.Responding.ToString();
            PName = p.ProcessName;
            VMsize = p.VirtualMemorySize64.ToString();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        return ("Success: , Responding: "+ responding + " Name: " + PName + " VMemory Size: " + VMsize);
    }
```

Comment: i have solved this